# Select items vs checkboxes vs radiobutons

Tags: web-app, android, interface, hci, filter

We were working in a system interface refactoring here on our web-based and its Android-based system when a question was raised: dealing with the following options in a report filter: "ALL USERS", "ACTIVE USERS" or "INACTIVE USERS", which would be the suitable component to inquire user?

1. A radio button with the 3 options
2. two checkboxes with "ACTIVE USERS" and "INACTIVE USERS"
3. a select menu with all 3 above options.

I'm not asking dev-based opinion, but the best choice based on web patterns and HCI conventions.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Radio buttons with all 3 options

This is a very common scenario, and many sites use either select or radio buttons interchangeably. However, it's recommended to have all options visible at all times, not to mention *radio buttons* take only one click, while *select* requires `click-->travel-->select`

> If possible, use radio buttons rather than drop-down menus. Radio
>   buttons have lower cognitive load because they make all options
>   visible so that users can easily compare them.
>
> In case you have less than 7 options you should consider using radio
>   buttons. Your users will be able immediately scan how many options
>   they have and what each of those options are, without clicking (or
>   typing) anything to reveal this information.

You can see more at [Radio Buttons UX Design](http://babich.biz/radio-buttons-ux-design/)